# boost parallel graph synchronize graph and local_subgraph adaptor

Tags: boost, graph, parallel-processing

I am trying to understand the code of distributed_adjacency_list_test.cpp, and I do not quite understand what the local subgraph adaptor does, as the code appears in below. Is local_g1 instance just a copy of g1 ?  Also what does synchronize(g1) do ?

```
local_subgraph<Graph1> local_g1(g1);
if (num_vertices(local_g1) > 0) {
  out_edges(*vertices(local_g1).first, local_g1);
  in_edges(*vertices(local_g1).first, local_g1);
  adjacent_vertices(*vertices(local_g1).first, local_g1);
  if (false) {
    cout << "if false ? " << endl;
    remove_out_edge_if(*vertices(g1).first, never<Graph1>(), g1);
    remove_in_edge_if(*vertices(g1).first, never<Graph1>(), g1);
    clear_out_edges(*vertices(g1).first, g1);
    clear_in_edges(*vertices(g1).first, g1);
    clear_vertex(*vertices(g1).first, g1);
    remove_vertex(*vertices(g1).first, g1);
  }
}
remove_edge_if(never<Graph1>(), g1);
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/pbgl/documentation/process_group.html

Comment: I only saw synchronize(ProcessGroup ) not the graph.

Comment: "When the PG is synchronized, all of the distributed data structures attached to that PG are automatically synchronized, so that all of the distributed data structures in a computation remain synchronized". Clearly the `synchronize` on a graph implements the mechanics to implement all data structures in a process group. Cf. the wording in [Property Map](http://tinyurl.com/kotsj8m): "_While the syntax and semantics are similar, distributed property maps may contain out-of-date information that can only be guaranteed to be synchronized by calling the synchronize function in all processes._"

Comment: @sehe Thanks for the reply.  After all data structures in a process group was synchronized, how do I find the global indices of the vertices ? Now it seems like the processes can only access the local vertices they own from this test example.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/vertex_list_adaptor.html